# Java "fresh type variable"

Tags: java, jls

What does "fresh type variable" mean in the JLS [Conversions and Promotions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#190795) chapter?

Comment: I'll explain it to you, if you explain to me what Capture Conversion is :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Fresh* is the common designation for a variable that must not have been used before.