# Compiler error using Java generics Interface with JavaFX Collection

Tags: java, generics, collections, interface, observablelist

I'm trying to use an interface with a JavaFX ListView to allow multiple object types to be displayed in the list at different points in the application (different Object type on different GUI screens. I have defined the ListView in my JavaFX controller class as:

```
@FXML private static ListView<? extends ListDisplayObj> lvLeftBarItems;
```

and `ListDisplayObj` is a simple interface:

```
public interface ListDisplayObj
{
    public String getListDisplayString();
}
```

I have a database-level method which obtains a list of objects to be displayed based on a given key - the method is defined as:

```
public ObservableList<? extends ListDisplayObj> getListObjectsForKey(String selectedKey)
{
    ...
}
```

Later in the controller event handler (or initialize() method) I am trying to initialize the ListView using an ObservableList as follows:

```
ObservableList<? extends ListDisplayObj> ol = MyObjectManager.getListObjectsForKey(selectedKey);
lvLeftBarItems.setItems(ol);
```

The `lvLeftBarItems.setItems(ol)` call generates the following compiler error (in Netbeans)::

```
incompatible types: ObservableList<CAP#1> cannot be converted to ObservableList<CAP#2>
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends ListDisplayObj from capture of ? extends ListDisplayObj
    CAP#2 extends ListDisplayObj from capture of ? extends ListDisplayObj
```

Any suggestions? I'm not sure how to resolve this. I've tried variations on using the raw Object (which implements ListDisplayObj) instead of `<? extends ListDisplayObj>`, just returning `<ListDisplayObj>` vs `<? extends ListDisplayObj>`, etc with no luck.

Comment: Anyone know what's meant by a "fresh type-variable" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733644/java-fresh-type-variable

Answer (score 0):

When you have a list whose element type is X you can store any object whose type is X or subclass of X.

```
ListView<? extends ListDisplayObj> lvLeftBarItems;
```

This declaration means that `lvLeftBarItems` is a `ListView` whose contents are some unspecified subclass of `ListDisplayObj`, lets name it CAP#1 (i know it is not a valid class name, but lets pass it for example purposes).

You are trying to add an element whose type is technically unspecified subclass of `ListDisplayObj` too, but lets name it CAP#2.

Now assume that CAP#1 extends ListDisplayObj and CAP#2 extends ListDisplayObj , so it is obvious that you can not cast an instance of CAP#1 to CAP#2 or vice-verse, and it follows that you can not cast a list of CAP#1 to a list of CAP#2, and this is exactly what compiler means when it says that "ObservableList cannot be converted to ObservableList" - these lists have a different incompatible type, because list items have a different incompatible type.

Check [GenericsFAQ: Which methods and fields are accessible/inaccessible through a reference variable of a wildcard parameterized type](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ304) for a more detailed explanation.

As for your code, simply replace the declaration of `lvLeftBarItems` to non-wildcard generic:

```
ListView<ListDisplayObj> lvLeftBarItems;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that's how I started out (pre-wildcard use) and it didn't work. I had defined `ListView<ListDisplayObj> lvLeftBarItems;`, and attempted to use `ObservableList<ListDisplayObj> = MyObjectManager.getListObjectsForKey(selectedKey);` which returns ObservableList<ConcreteObject> where `ConcreteObject implements ListDisplayObj`. Note it's an interface (implements not extends). In that case, the compiler rejects the assignment to the collection from the utility method saying that the types are incompatible. Perhaps I should post that question separately.